# Some keys on Apple Wireless keyboard not working

Tags: macos, keyboard

I noticed that these keys are not working on my Apple Wireless keyboard: `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`, `t`, `y`, `u`, `i`, & `o`. All the other keys work normally. The keyboard layout is set to `US`.

Is there a setting that I enabled accidentally or it is time to get a new keyboard?

Comment: I'd consider checking it by pairing with other devices like an iPhone, iPad or a Windows PC before reaching a conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting or keyboard layout that will render an entire row of keys disabled.

Consider checking the keyboard by pairing it with other device that you have access to such as another Mac, Windows PC equipped with Bluetooth, an iPhone/iPod or an iPad.

If the behaviour reoccurs, than most likely the keyboard is kaput. If the keyboard is still covered under original warranty or the accompanying Mac is covered under original warranty or Apple Care, you can get it inspected or replaced at an Apple Store or authorised Apple service centre.

Comment: I paired the keyboard w/ an ipad and the behavior persisted.  Time for a new keyboard...